# How to display image from folder into picturebox

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2019

I have stored the image path into the column NewImage(varchar) and when I want to display that image from my Images folder its showing a white box with red cross on the picture box.

[image: Storing image path into NewImage column]

[image: Storing images in Images directory]

This is the code where i try to retrieve the image from my Images directory and its not working

```
private void Quiz_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                pictureBox1.Image = null;       
            }

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
           
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NewImage FROM tblQuestion WHERE QuestionId =1", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            
                            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = (@"\Images");
                           
                           
                            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
                            conn.Close();
                        }

                    }

                }
                
            }
```

[image: Output:]

Answer (score 0):

Form Design:

The below Form consists of a Button, a Label and a PictureBox control.

[image]

Namespaces
You will need to import the following namespaces.

C#:

using System.IO;

using System.Drawing;

Displaying Images from Folder (Directory) in PictureBox
When the Choose File Button is clicked, the OpenFileDialog is opened and the Image file is selected.
The selected Image file is displayed in PictureBox control using the FromFile function of the Image class.

```
   private void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lblFileName.Text = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

[https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Image-from-Folder-Directory-in-PictureBox-control-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx#:~:text=Displaying%20Images%20from%20Folder%20%28Directory%29%20in%20PictureBox%20When,using%20the%20FromFile%20function%20of%20the%20Image%20class](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Image-from-Folder-Directory-in-PictureBox-control-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx#:%7E:text=Displaying%20Images%20from%20Folder%20%28Directory%29%20in%20PictureBox%20When,using%20the%20FromFile%20function%20of%20the%20Image%20class).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what I am trying to do is to show a quiz question which has image above it

Comment: Hello, is your problem solved now?

Comment: Nope it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Then I suggest you add the relative path of the picture:

1.Absolute path:

```
this.pictureBox.Image=Image.FromFile("C:\\test.jpg");
```

2.Relative path:

```
Application.StartupPath;
```

You can get the program root

```
this.pictureBox.Image=Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath "\\test.jpg");
```

3.Get the path to the web picture

```
string url="http://img.zcool.cn/community/01635d571ed29832f875a3994c7836.png@900w_1l_2o_100sh.jpg";
this.pictureBox.Image= Image.FromStream(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the data you get from the database into **datatable dt** and don't use it. Check to see if the directory is correctly fetched in **dt** and apply it to **pictureBox1**.